# ReSharper suggests "convert to ?? expression", but how?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Using ReSharper 7.1.1 in Visual Studio 2012. Sample code:

```cs
private string _str;

private string TheString
{
    get
    {
        if (_str == null) // "X"
        {
            _str = GetString();
        }
        return _str;
    }
}

// do some work to get string. e.g. read from database
private string GetString()
{
    return "blah";
}
```

At the line marked "X", ReSharper underlines the "if" statement and suggests "Convert to ?? expression". But how? Am I missing something?

Comment: it should do it for you?

Comment: yes, you are right. My original confusion was trying to figure out how this code could be refactored (e.g. by hand, even without using resharper).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your code,

Click on the 'if' where its saying it wants to use the ??

press ALT-ENTER

or click on the lightbulb

it will then have an option to convert,  either press enter, or click on it with the mouse and you will get

```
        private string _str;

        private string TheString
        {
            get { return _str ?? (_str = GetString()); }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't see the light bulb (i must be going blind <g>). I must say though, in this case I find my original version easier to read. I guess this is subjective (?).

Comment: its a little bit subjective, these things are idioms / syntactic sugar, if you use them regularly, then they are just as easy to read.  Some people prefer the conciseness,  I know I do.  BUT resharper has lots of transforms that may end up worse, its just a tool and a suggestion, best idea is ALT-ENTER -> ENTER  you get the changed code, look at it, then undo it if you don't like it

Answer (score 3):

Keith pretty much answered your question. Here's the screenshot of the light blub:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not to directly answer your question but note that there's a simple way to do this using `Lazy<T>`:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    private readonly Lazy<string> _str;

    public Foo()
    {
        _str = new Lazy<string>(GetString);
    }

    private string TheString
    {
        get
        {
            return _str.Value;
        }
    }

    private string GetString()
    {
        return "blah";
    }
}
```

Since you're making `TheString` a private property I assume it's only there to bundle up the whole make-if-not-set process, so you can probably remove it and just use `_str.Value` everywhere.

(You can also easily make this threadsafe by passing an option into the `Lazy` constructor.)